# How to subscribe to PROCESS_STATE_RUNNING events for all processes

Tags: python, supervisord

I'm using [Supervisor's events framework](http://supervisord.org/events.html) to subscribe to events from processes managed by Supervisor.

My event listener, `processlistener.py`, looks like this:

```py
import sys

from supervisor.childutils import listener

def write_stdout(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()


def main():
    while True:
        headers, body = listener.wait(sys.stdin, sys.stdout)
        body = dict([pair.split(":") for pair in body.split(" ")])

        write_stderr("Headers: %r\n" % repr(headers))
        write_stderr("Body: %r\n" % repr(body))

        if headers["eventname"] == "PROCESS_STATE_RUNNING":
            write_stderr("Process state running...\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In my `supervisord.conf`, I have:

```
[program:theprogramname]
command=/bin/cat              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)

[eventlistener:theeventlistenername]
command=python processlistener.py    ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s       ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                           ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
events=PROCESS_STATE_RUNNING         ; event notif. types to subscribe to (req'd)
```

With this configuration, I am expecting my event listener to be notified whenever a process managed by Supervisor enters the `RUNNING` state. However, this is not the case. When I kill `theprogramname` with a `SIGINT` signal, the process is restarted by Supervisor, but my listener doesn't get notified of this.

Am I missing an extra piece of configuration in order to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your listener needs to send a 'RESULT 2\nOK' response back to supervisord on stdout.

If supervisord doesn't see this response, it thinks that your listener is not ready and won't send any more events.

Try adding this inside your while loop:

```
listener.ok(sys.stdout)
```

This tells the listener to send the 'OK' response.

Here is the source for the `ok` method in `supervisor.childutils.listener`:
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/3.0/supervisor/childutils.py#L61