# Supervisor events: how to listen for PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED events for all or specified processes

Tags: python, supervisord

I'm trying to use supervisord events to listen to `PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED` events from processes managed by Supervisor.

My event listener (`listener.py`), looks like this:

```
import sys

from supervisor.childutils import listener

def write_stdout(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()


def main():
    while True:
        headers, body = listener.wait(sys.stdin, sys.stdout)
        body = dict([pair.split(":") for pair in body.split(" ")])
        write_stderr("Headers: %r\n" % repr(headers))
        write_stderr("Body: %r\n" % repr(body))
        listener.ok(sys.stdout)

        if headers["eventname"] == "PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED":
            write_stderr("Process state stopped...\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My corresponding entry in `supervisord.conf` is as follows:

```
[program:theprogramname]
command=/bin/cat              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
...
[eventlistener:theeventlistenername]
command=python /home/mickm/listener.py    ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s       ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                           ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
events=PROCESS_STATE                 ; event notif. types to subscribe to (req'd)
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

I've researched the other StackOverflow questions on this area & I've attempted to implement accepted solutions from:

- [How to subscribe to PROCESS_STATE_RUNNING events for all processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413914/how-to-subscribe-to-process-state-running-events-for-all-processes)
- [Supervisor event subscription is hanging on READY state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535635/supervisor-event-subscription-is-hanging-on-ready-state)

However, when I run `listener.py` , it outputs `READY` to SDOUT & goes no further. I've tried stopping/starting & restarting supervisor-monitored processes, but my script does pick up anything.

To test this, I'm:

1. running my event listener script in terminal A;
2. performing a `kill -9 <pid>` on the `/bin/cat` process in terminal B.

My supervisor log is as follows:

```
2017-01-13 14:56:36,168 INFO success: theeventlistenername_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-01-13 14:56:36,168 INFO success: theprogramname entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-01-13 14:57:29,457 INFO exited: theprogramname (terminated by SIGKILL; not expected)
2017-01-13 14:57:30,460 INFO spawned: 'theprogramname' with pid 25788
2017-01-13 14:57:31,462 INFO success: theprogramname entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

While the the supervisor log knows my process has been terminated:

i)  Nothing is detected by `listener.py`, which remains at 'READY' prompt.

ii) supervisor restarts to process (as expected).

I'm wondering why the listener is not picking up the `PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED` event for the program defined in the config file (as per Supervisor event [docs](http://supervisord.org/events.html)). Also - whether this can be applied generally for all supervisor-managed processes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuration variable **redirect_stderr:**

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

> Do not set redirect_stderr=true in an [eventlistener:x] section.
>   Eventlisteners use stdout and stdin to communicate with supervisord.
>   If stderr is redirected, output from stderr will interfere with the
>   eventlistener protocol.

This is my working script:

```
import sys

from supervisor.childutils import listener

def write_stdout(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()

def main():
    while True:
        headers, body = listener.wait(sys.stdin, sys.stdout)
        body = dict([pair.split(":") for pair in body.split(" ")])

        write_stderr("Headers: %r\n" % repr(headers))
        write_stderr("Body: %r\n" % repr(body))

        if headers["eventname"] == "PROCESS_STATE_STOPPING":
            write_stderr("Process state stopping...\n")

        # acknowledge the event
        write_stdout("RESULT 2\nOK")
```

But I believe you cannot test it simply running your script. Your supervisorctl .conf file has some special env variables like **events** which doesnt appear when you run your script manually

If you want to test it then add some logging to your listener:

```
[eventlistener:theeventlistenername]
command=python /home/mickm/listener.py    ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s       ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                           ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
events=PROCESS_STATE           ; event notif. types to subscribe to (req'd)
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=errorlogfile
stdout_logfile=applogfile
```

Also you can debug **headers** variable and you can check the data you are receiving.

With the logging enabled you can test it with a **tail -f error.log.path** on the **stderr_logfile** logfile.

```
 Headers: "{'ver': '3.0', 'poolserial': '4', 'len': '71', 'server': 'supervisor', 'eventname': 'PROCESS_STATE_RUNNING', 'serial': '4', 'pool': 'mylistener'}" 
 Body: "{'from_state': 'STARTING', 'processname': 'someprocess', 'pid': '345', 'groupname': 'someprocess'}" 
 Process state running...
```

And when I kil -9 the process the above output appears in the log.

Also the stdout_logfile will log this kind of information:

```
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
```

Comment: Can you restart any supervisorctl process? or kill it? and check if the error.log is being generated

Comment: Ah I see, also dont use redirect_stderr when using an eventlistener, check my edit

Comment: You will have to restart whole supervisord service when removing redirct property. Supervisorctl update is not enough in this case.

Comment: I can't see you write READY to stdout, am I missing something?

Comment: dont you think its nice to give an example we can simply copy and paste in our pc. As a newbie I needed code :)